# Why does the Linux kernel require small short-term memory chunks in odd sizes？

Tags: linux, memory-management, operating-system

I'm reading *Operating System: Internals and Design Principles* by William Stallings, 7th edition. In section 8.4 Linux Memory Management, when talking about *kernel memory management*, it goes like:

> The foundation of kernel memory allocation for Linux is the page allocation
>   mechanism used for user virtual memory management. As in the virtual memory
>   scheme, a buddy algorithm is used so that memory for the kernel can be allocated
>   and deallocated in units of one or more pages. Because the minimum amount of
>   memory that can be allocated in this fashion is one page, the page allocator alone
>   would be inefficient because the kernel requires small short-term memory chunks
>   in odd sizes.

I could understand the discuss on paging, but why does the author says that **the kernel requires small short-term memory chunks
in odd sizes.**, especially, why **in odd sizes**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because most programs require small allocations, for relatively short periods, in a variety of sizes? That's why `malloc` and friends exist: To subdivide the larger allocations from the OS into smaller pieces with sub-page-size granularity. Want a linked list (commonly needed in OS kernels)? You need to be able to allocate small nodes that contain the value and a pointer to the next node (and possibly a reverse pointer too).

I suspect by "odd sizes" they just mean "arbitrary sizes"; I don't expect the kernel to be unusually heavy on 1, 3, 5, 7, etc. byte allocations, but the allocation sizes are, in many cases, not likely to be consistent enough that a fixed block allocator is broadly applicable. Writing a special block allocator for each possible linked list node size (let alone every other possible size needed for dynamically allocated memory) isn't worth it unless that linked list is absolutely performance critical after all.

Comment: That part is talking about kernel memory management, so is the fact that programs require small allocations related?

Comment: @Mark: The kernel is a "program" too. More complex than most sure, but it still needs to do most things user-level programs need to do, plus all the special stuff kernels need to handle. The needs, as far as memory allocation go, are similar enough.

Comment: I see. Could you please give some examples to show the kernel needs small allocations?

Comment: @Mark: I gave the obvious case of a linked list already. If you search `kernel linked list` in your favorite search engine, you'll immediately see several articles on the subject. Or just `grep` the Linux kernel source code for uses of `kmalloc` (the Linux kernel equivalent of `malloc`). Asking "why it needs small allocations" is kind of odd; why does *any* program need small allocations? The answer is the same for the kernel as for any program.